# Randomly getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
success: function(data) {
    var timeslots = new Array('09:00am', '09:15am', '09:30am', '09:45am', '10:00am', '10:15am', '10:30am', '10:45am', '11:00am', '11:15am', '11:30am', '11:45am', '02:00pm', '02:15pm', '02:30pm', '02:45pm', '03:00pm', '03:15pm', '03:30pm', '03:45pm', '04:00pm', '04:15pm', '04:30pm');
    var booked = '';
    var bookedSlots = [];
    var t_slots;

    if (data.bookedslots.length == timeslots.length) {
        if (manageDay) {
            $('.manageSlots .timeSlot').remove();
        }
        alert('No Available Slots');
        $(where).find('select.time').empty();
        return false;
    }

    for (var t = 0; t < data.bookedslots.length; t++) {
        booked = data.bookedslots[t]['time'].substr(0, data.bookedslots[t]['time'].length - 3);
        bookedSlots.push(booked);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < timeslots.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < bookedSlots.length; j++) {
            ///// getting the error on this line ////////if(timeslots[i].substring(0,5) === bookedSlots[j]){
            timeslots.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

```
    for (var z = 0; z < timeslots.length; z++) {
        t_slots += '<option value="' + timeslots[z] + '">' + timeslots[z] + '</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly `timeslots[i]` is undefined.  When you debug this, what is its value?

Comment: timeslots is the array that is hardcoded in the return function. I dont understand how what is undefined. When I log both timeslots and bookedSlots, they read in the console fine. The error is happening when bookedSlots(which is returned from the database) is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have spliced out timeslots[i], but in the next iteration of j you try to use it.  If it was the last item in the array you will get an error.  If you splice, you should break on the next line to abort the rest of the j loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < timeslots.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < bookedSlots.length; j++) {
        if(timeslots[i].substring(0,5) === bookedSlots[j]){
          timeslots.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was the last item in timeslots that was undefined.